# fread() reads from current file and old file

Tags: c, text, fread

When I use this code

```
FILE *f = fopen(file, "rb");
const char *d;
if (f!=NULL) {
    static char c[100000];
    fread(c, sizeof(char), 10000000, f);
    d = c;
    fclose(f);
    return d;
}
else{
    /*
     char *ff = f;
     perror(ff);
     */
    d = "Error";
    fclose(f);
    return d;
}
```

to read from a file that has text like this

```
This
Is a test
```

it reads it fine. However, if I open a different file that has this text

```
Test
```

it will read something like

```
Test Is a test
```

Why does it combine both into one when the file is closed?
I put this now, but I still get the same results

```
if (f!=NULL) {
fread(c, sizeof(c), len, f);
d = c;
fclose(f);
c[99999] = '\0';
return d;
}
```

Comment: You must terminate your strings with the null character; `fread` won't do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

`fread()` doesn't NUL-terminate the buffer which it reads to. If the second read is shorter than the first one, the rest of the first which is not overwritten will remain there. And anyway your program invokes undefined behavior at so many places it's not even funny.

For example, this:

```
static char c[100000];
fread(c, sizeof(char), 10000000, f);
```

is most likely a typo - you're allowing `fread()` to read 100 times more data than the size of the buffer. That's why you should ***always*** (I mean, ***A-L-W-A-Y-S***) use the `sizeof()` operator and the size of the array element instead of its type. Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, don't spell out redundant data:

```
fread(c, sizeof(c), 1, f);
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there are characters left in your array from the last read. You should null terminate the string before returning, `fread()` won't do this for you.

You've got some other issues too, such as the character limit for `fread()` being way bigger than your buffer size.

Unless you really need c for this, you should think about using c++ or even some other language with more sophisticated file and text processing libraries, it would make your life easier.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam: You should probably get in the habit of using `sizeof(buffer)`

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the data into a static buffer, and you don't terminate the string when you're done. 
Since `c` is static, it is zero initialized. You partly overwrite that with the data from the `fread()` call.

So, you should use the returned value from `fread()` and set `c[len]` to `'\0'`.